# Could a mixed Anova be used if the level of the between subjects IV differs across the within subjects IV?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design

I have a pilot experiment that gives 2 stories (A and B) to the participants and they answer the same survey questions after each story. Importantly, each story can be competent (COMP) or incompetent (IN-COMP), and the competency level of one story can be different from the other.

Basically, it is a 2x2 design (competency level for story A, competency level for story B) with 2 scores per participant (score for story A, score for story B).

Here is an example of it in wide and long formats below.

**WIDE**

| Subject | A-Competence | A-Score | B-Competence | B-Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COMP | 4 | IN-COMP | 2 |
| 2 | IN-COMP | 3 | IN-COMP | 2 |
| 3 | IN-COMP | 3 | COMP | 5 |

**LONG**

| Subject | Story | Competence | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | COMP | 4 |
| 1 | B | IN-COMP | 2 |
| 2 | A | IN-COMP | 3 |
| 2 | B | IN-COMP | 2 |
| 3 | A | IN-COMP | 3 |
| 3 | B | COMP | 5 |

I am struggling to figure out how to do analysis on the competency levels. I know I could do a paired-samples t-test for story type (story A vs B) but that isn't really what interests me. In a perfect world, I would want to do a t-test for COMP vs. IN-COMP collapsing across stories but since the level of competency of one story may differ from the other, this seems impossible to collapse within subjects. I would be fine settling for a two-way ANOVA but I don't even think I could do a 2-way ANOVA (or MANOVA) as the scores (being about the specific story A or B) are not contingently affected by *both* independent variables. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Simply, is there a way I can analyze this data without needing to do a separate T-test for each story?